# When I resume from suspension - the screen is blank

Tags: 10.04, suspend, suspend-resume

I use ubuntu 10.04 in HP Pavilion dv4 2165 dx. After putting my computer in suspend, when I open the scree comes very low brightness; even I cannot see anything there, so eventually I press the power button to shut down and start it again. It happens every time. How to solve this problem.
thanks

Comment: Have you tried clicking the left mouse button?

Comment: Did you encrypt your swap / are you using the encrypt home folder option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're affected by [bug #578673](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/578673) (the key for searching was to search for the model of your video controller: Intel HD Graphics). Make sure you have recommended updates (`lucid-updates`) checked in the “Updates” tab of the Update Manager settings, and that you have the latest kernel (at least 2.6.32-24.42).

If that doesn't help, read through the comments and see if someone has made a suggestion that might help you. If you can't find anything, report a new bug. Be sure to mention your exact hardware and kernel version and that the fix for bug #578673 didn't help you.